# 1999 Eclipse Anti-theft reset

Tags: mitsubishi

Does anyone know how to reset the anti theft system on a 1999 Eclipse GST? 
I replaced the vehicle battery and the starter will not engage now. This happened to me once before when I disconnected the battery to replace the head gasket. Can't remember what i did to fix it...
I've tried locking and unlocking the doors with the key fob, and manually. Windows up, down, hatch open, closed, hood open, closed. 
I have the owners manual but there's nothing regarding this in the battery section or the alarm section.

Comment: With all doors closed, try locking and unlocking drivers door with the Key, then see if it starts.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it today. I thought I'd post the results since I'm always mad when people don't follow up and post the final fix. The car had a Loctronics unit installed. Apparently it's an added immobilizer unit that takes an electronic (looks like a circuit board or SD card) key. It interrupts the main power to the starter relay. Removed that crap, restored the original car wiring, and it starts up every time. Not sure why it was randomly starting before. Thanks again for your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the alarm or the immobilizer? I'm guessing since you said you tried turning it off with the remote then its the immobilizer.

For immobilizer, your only option is to reprogram the key via eeprom or a obdII tool with the functions for programming this key. There is no manual programming for this year eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes I believe it's the immobilizer. The alarm (horn honking) has never gone off. The starter will not engage at all. Just nothing when you turn the key. It also has something called a Locktronics. I have overcome this problem before when I changed the head gasket.... i disconnected the battery to prevent accidental start up

Comment: Most cars have security lights that blink or go solid. For some reason Mitsubishi's light never work right so it is hard to know for sure with out scanning DTC's. Depending on your area you can call a local locksmith to come out and program it for you. Around these parts I charge about $60-$90 max but may be a different market where you are.

Comment: What's weird is I can't figure out how I corrected this before. I should have written it down. I remember I finished the head gasket, hooked up the battery. No start. I remember checking voltages all around, etc. Then it just started.

Comment: It would have to be something else (at least the last time then). There is no way to relearn the key manually. If I remember correctly this one uses a separate immobilizer box. So this box stores a ID that is also stored in the key. When you turn the ignition they verify with each other briefly and when they match the immo box then sends a verify code to the ecu to say its ok to let things run. The lost key id data in immobilizer box or verify code in ecu should not happen, but it does sometimes. Once lost tho , the only way to correct it is to program the key. (eeprom or obd programmer).

Comment: Maybe your just having grounding issue? If you could have someone check dtc's for you it would rule out or point the finger for sure at the immobilizer.

Comment: My roommate has a code reader. Pretty stupid for a car designer to design this system with no fail safe for the owner. PIN number or something. I've been a Harley mechanic for 20 years and even Harley has a PIN number for their security system.

Comment: No codes and its randomly starting and running now. Just fired it up and drove about 5 miles. Returned home, shut it off, won't crank. Have you ever seen a transponder key starting to fail? Intermittent? Thanks for the info before on the keys, etc. Good stuff to know.

Comment: Yes, sometimes the antenna receiver around ignition starts failing and can be intermittent. Its not common on these tho. You can usually check this by unhooking it and move it close to key. Rarely the chips in key goes bad. Usually when they do its not intermittent.

Comment: Fixed it today. I thought I'd post the results since I'm always mad when people don't follow up and post the final fix. The car had a Loctronics unit installed. Apparently it's an added immobilizer unit that takes an electronic (looks like a circuit board or SD card) key. It interrupts the main power to the starter relay. Removed that crap, restored the original car wiring, and it starts up every time. Not sure why it was randomly starting before. Thanks again for your help on this.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up! I have taken out a lot of after market remote starts and passlocks from failures causing issue's like this so I am not surprised. Sorry I had never heard of the name of yours before and did not look it up. I assumed it was just a entry alarm.